# how to get week of year with friday as starting date using mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling to get week of year (from 1 to 52) in mysql query using friday as starting date. My friend said just add current date with number (because friday is 5 and sunday as default starting date is 0) 5 so that we can know week of year of given date.

What function will satisfy this problem? as for given that if value is 2009-12-28, it will ruin the function itself?

thanks before

Comment: Never heard of Friday-based weeks; `strftime` supports `%U` for Sunday-based weeks, `%V` for ISO 8601 "first week with four or more days at the start of the year", and `%W` for Monday-based weeks. Could your application use one of these standardized weeks instead? If not, you may need to do some heavy lifting yourself.

Comment: this is not option as my office using friday as starting date. i think if this is not in sql query it will be much easier

Answer (score 1):

i got a trick

```
select week(from_days(to_days('2010-01-01') + 2)) as week, '2010-01-01'
```

but if someone can give better answer, i will appreciate since i'm not sure about my method
also if i give '2010-12-31' as answer, it's stuck